# Listview builder not updating values in list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a positioned ListViewBuilder inside a Stack attempting to show a dynamic drop down across multiple tiles with different drop down values. This seems to work fine, except for the fact that the values don't seem to clear correctly when the list is updated with new values and refreshed on SetState.

ListView builder code

```
Positioned(
              top: 100,
              left: 100,
              width: 90,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: dropDownListValues.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Tile(
                    tileId: dropDownListValues[index],
                    isHeaderTile: false,
                    uuid: Uuid().v1(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Clear and update list based on which button is pressed.

```
  void _toggleDropDown(List valueList) {
    if (dropDownListValues.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        dropDownListValues = valueList;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        dropDownListValues.clear();
      });
    }
  }
```

What I end up getting is the list extends based on the number of items in the drop down, but the values from the previous list carry across from the last list..

Example.

**Drop Down list values**

```
Dropdown list 1 = ['one', 'two']
Dropdown list 2 = ['two', 'three', 'four']
```

**What I am seeing is**

```
Dropdown list 1 = ['one', 'two']
Dropdown list 2 = ['one', 'two', 'four']
```

**The if I click on list two drop down first I get the following**

```
Dropdown list 1 = ['two', 'three']
Dropdown list 2 = ['two', 'three', 'four']
```

Im stumped and have spend hours on this, any idea what I could be doing wrong to cause this refresh issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what result you are expecting?

Comment: I was expecting that the drop downs replicated the values in the lists. It seems that the list index's that have already been used by preview drop downs aren't being updated, however, if the new drop downs count is higher, it will fill the remaining index with the right values. It's a wierd one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`keys`](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d) so the Flutter Framework can identify changes to your list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am using keys in the constructor of my StatefulWidget (Tile)

Comment: Can't see it on your sample.

Comment: I was using it but not properly. This is now working, thanks for the suggestion